# Browser Default ICON

Tags: browser, icons, default

How can I get the default browser ICON ?

I need to show the ICON of the current default browser.

Comment: Are you talking about the graphic that appears in the location bar of the web browser for a particular website, or the icon that appears on the desktop of your graphical OS for launching the browser?

Comment: Yes the ICO that appears in the desktop.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, can you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a **shortcut icon** or **favicon**

First, create a 16 x 16 pixel graphic.
You may need to [download a plugin](http://see.weareinto.com/3qR1) if you're using photoshop.

Then, the HTML is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Content -->
    </body>
</html>
```